# Is there a scriptable Java tool that can perform garbage collection on a running JVM?

Tags: java, scripting, garbage-collection

It is simple enough to perform garbage collection on a running JVM using the `jconsole` or `jvisualvm` tools that ship with the JDK, and it's very nice to be able to script some collection of statistics using the `jstat` command on a system where there is remote shell access but no X11 access or RMI access.

However, I've found no tool in the JDK that lets me perform garbage collection on a running process that I can invoke from an SSH session without a DISPLAY environment.

Is there really no such command-line tool in the JDK but only GUI tools that have the "perform GC" button, or am I missing something?

edit: I know I could write such a tool.  And yes, I know the JVM does GC when it needs to do so, so repeating that mantra will not help anything.  The application is running fine, and I simply want to poke it to see how much memory it's using without either taking it off-line (no restarting the existing JVM) or deploying some new code to the environment where it's running because that's not something I can make happen in the near term.  Doing investigations like this is a big reason there are tools such as `jconsole` and `jvisualvm` that will perform GC when you click the GUI button, but it would be nice not to have to try go jump through X-forwarding hoops just to perform a simple task.

Comment: Something in the JDK is what I'm after.  I could easily write such a tool, but that would take take a long time to get deployed to this particular environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a simple non-GUI Java application, or a Scala/JRuby/Jython/Groovy/whatever script, to establish a JMX connection to your JVM ([server VM configuration](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/agent.html), [sample client code](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/remote/custom.html)) and use that to call the `gc()` operation on the `java.lang:type=Memory` MBean (assuming a Sun/Oracle JVM) from the command line. You can use the same mechanism to retrieve memory usage information from some of the other MBeans.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I don't want to do right now because it would take weeks to get such code deployed to the environment where I want to do some investigation.   That's why I said it would be easy to write such a tool as you note, but I'm wondering why such a tool does not exist in the JDK except for those that require a GUI.

Comment: It might be possible to use `jrunscript`, but even that might require "code" to be deployed to this environment, and I really do not have that option as noted above.

Comment: Barend, are you saying, "No, there is not such a tool?"

Comment: I don't know of any such tool included with the JDK by default. You have SSH to the server, is there really no way you could open vi, write a .java file to tmp, run javac and execute the class file?

Comment: I could, but that would likely contravene company policy.  We've made do with ssh and X forwarding.

Comment: Agreed, better safe than sorry.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no need for such a tool.

The JVM will know when to garbage collect, there is no reason to initiate the collection "from the outside"

Comment: That is not why I want to do garbage collection.  The application runs fine, thanks.  I want to use it for investigative purposes, and I'm sorry if that was not completely clear in the original posting.